# equations involving functional differentiation

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question concerning equations involving functionals and it's functional derivatives. Can someone give me a book or paper where such equations are discussed?

By this, I mean equations like:

δJ/δf(x)=J

where J is the functional and δJ/δf(x) is functional derivative.

Comment: or at least some information?

Comment: You could consult a book in calculus of variation